# Is it possible to set a reminder in an iOS application that notifies the user with a custom popup on the phone without the application having to run?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, popup, reminders

I want to set a reminder in an application, close the application completely and then get a custom popup at the time my reminder was set.

I know about Local Notifications and Push Notifications but it seems like for Local Notifications to work the application must be open.

Thanks

Comment: who said that? uilocalnotification will work both in foreground and in  background.

Answer (score 2):

Do a bit more reading. [UILocalNotification docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly state in the first paragraph **The operating system is responsible for delivering the notification at the proper time; the application does not have to be running for this to happen.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just to get back to the question, can I have a custom popup appear outside the application. a Popup that does not look like the default popup.

I want to be able to set the colors, backgrounds etc.